# Coding HTML inner PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I`d like to do this:

```
<a href="...">
<img src="..." />
<h5>Older Post</h5>
<p>Titel</p>
</a>
```

### My code

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', "$prevthumbnail __('<h5>Older Post</h5>'), 
<p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
```

but doesn´t work at all. I´ve some syntax problems to combine PHP (WordPress translation) and HTML:

Thanks for your help
Ogni

## --- UPDATE ---

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', "$nextthumbnail", TRUE); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', __("<span class='header'>Older post</span>", "SCNR"), TRUE); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', "<span>%title</span>", TRUE); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried the WP codex? I think it explains this quite well. You can also check themes to see how they accomplish this.

Comment: PHP will not execute a function (which `__(...)` is) inside a double quoted string. You need to concatenate it in. Unquoted: `$prevthumbnail . __('<h5>Older Post</h5>') . "<p>%title</p>"`

Comment: See [the PHP manual on double-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: `"$prevthumbnail __('<h5>Older Post</h5>'), 
<p>%title</p>"` wont be executed. it should be `$prevthumbnail . __('<h5>Older Post</h5>'), "<p>%title</p>"`

Comment: Thanks, but doens't work for me

Comment: I updated my own code, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but it should work for what you need. Instead of using the `next_post_link()` function which was really meant for simpler links, we're building the link on our own.

```
<?php

// Gets the ID of the next post in the same term
$next_post = get_next_post( true );

// If that ID exists...
if ( ! empty( $next_post ) ) :

?>

  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post ); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $next_post ); ?>
    <h5><?php _e( 'Older Post', 'textdomain' ); ?></h5>
    <p><?php echo get_the_title( $next_post ); ?></p>
  </a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Does the next post have a post thumbnail?

Comment: Yes. This works for me `<?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(60,60, true) );?>
       <?php previous_post_link('%link', "$prevthumbnail" . __("<span class='header'>Previous post</span><span>%title</span>", "SCRN"), true); ?>`

Comment: That's not really the advisable way to do it from a translation perspective, but I'm glad you got something working.

Answer (score -2):

You need some serious help, try this instead.

```
<?php
   //connect to database and set variables or whatever
   $link = "http://foo.bar";
   $prevthumbnail = "img/foo.png";
   $title = "The Foo Bar";

   //then print this...
   echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><img src="'.$prevthumbnail.'" /><h5>Older Post</h5><p>'.$title.'</p></a>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can´t do it by variables, WordPress functions

Comment: you could throw it in a function... but that is the basic final output. I suggest not using wordpress, but it is hard to answer your question without knowing the function next_post_link($link, $code, bool Visible)... I don't know, that is what it looks like.

Comment: You suggest not using WordPress? How's that helpful? It's obvious it's a WordPress project — the solution to his not understanding a wordPress function is not to abandon WordPress entirely.

Comment: If you are a programmer, you shouldn't use WordPress period. Code your site from scratch and you will have less problems and fewer security risks.